# can I make an authorization check outside the function in laravel controller file?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, authorization

Everytime before I call the function in laravel, I check if the person who requests the ajax link is logged in. 
I have to put this check function inside every function to make it work. if I write outside the function it simply prints

> please login to see this content work.

even though I am logged in. Is there a way to put the check function in the beginning of the controller file so I don't have to write it it everytime inside the functions.

```
  function index()
                if(!\Auth::check()) 
                return response()->json(array(
                    'status'=>'error',
                    'message'=> 'Please login to see this content'
                ));
    return redirect('/login')->with('msgstatus', 'error')->with('messagetext','Please login to see this content'); }

    function loadcalendar()
                if(!\Auth::check()) 
                return response()->json(array(
                    'status'=>'error',
                    'message'=> 'Please login to see this content'
                ));
    //somedefinition 
  }  
    function savecalendar()
                if(!\Auth::check()) 
                return response()->json(array(
                    'status'=>'error',
                    'message'=> 'Please login to see this content'
                ));
    //somedefinition 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware).

Out of the box laravel has a `auth` middleware which checks if a user is logged in. To protect specific routes on your controller simply add this to your route:

```
Route::get('/', 'YourController@index')->middleware('auth');
```

or define it in the constructor or the controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

When using the constructor method, you can also specify for which method the middleware should be checked.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');

    $this->middleware('log')->only('index');

    $this->middleware('subscribed')->except('store');
}
```

See [Controller Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#controller-middleware) in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

From the Laravel Docs:

> Even though it is possible to determine if a user is authenticated
>   using the check method, you will typically use a middleware to verify
>   that the user is authenticated before allowing the user access to
>   certain routes / controllers. To learn more about this, check out the
>   documentation on protecting routes.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#protecting-routes

There is build-in middleware that does this:

Defining:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

in your controller for example will check every method on that controller against the auth middleware.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You may want construct here:

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

Every function requires authentication now.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller,
add this constructor method. This will use the built in Auth middleware and redirect any non logged in users to login page

```
 public function __construct()
    {  

        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```